# Configuration for Druid Kafka ingestion

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I want to setup kafka druid ingestion but Even after configuring in common.runtime.properties and adding druid - kafka indexing service it s still giving me error . Please help me out with this. My data is in csv format.

```
{
"type": "kafka",
"spec": {
    "dataSchema": {
        "dataSource": "london_crime_by_lsoa",
        "parser": {
            "type": "string",
            "parseSpec": {
                "format": "csv",
                "dimensionsSpec": {
                    "dimensions": [
                        "lsoa_code",
                        "borough",
                        "major_category",
                        "minor_category",
                        {
                            "name": "value",
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "year",
                            "type": "long"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "month",
                            "type": "long"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "timestampSpec": {
                    "column": "year",
                    "format": "auto"
                },
                "columns": [
                    "lsoa_code",
                    "borough",
                    "major_category",
                    "minor_category",
                    "value",
                    "year",
                    "month"
                ]
            }
        },
        "metricsSpec": [],
        "granularitySpec": {
            "type": "uniform",
            "segmentGranularity": "year",
            "queryGranularity": "NONE",
            "rollup": false
        }
    },
    "ioConfig": {
        "topic": "london_crime_by_lsoa",
        "taskDuration": "PT10M",
        "useEarliestOffset": "true",
        "consumerProperties": {
            "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"
        }
    },
    "tuningConfig": {
        "type": "kafka",
        "maxRowsPerSegment": 500000
    }
}
```

}

After executing this command:

```
   curl -XPOST -H'Content-Type: application/json' -d @quickstart/tutorial/crime_supervisor.json http://localhost:8090/druid/indexer/v1/supervisor
```

I am getting this error :

```
{"error":"Instantiation of [simple type, class org.apache.druid.indexing.kafka.supervisor.KafkaSupervisorSpec] value failed: dataSchema"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a problem with the way you specified spec in your JSON.
You have to specify `dataSchema` directly in your JSON instead of as a child attribute of `spec`.

Here's the format you should follow:

```
{
   "type": "kafka",
   "dataSchema": {},
   "tuningConfig": {},
   "ioConfig": {}
}
```